# Is there a function to convert a string to an integer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, string, integer

I would like to convert for example the string "98" to the integer 98. Also, is there a way to specify that the value contained in the string is in hexadecimal and that "98" gets converted to 152?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Convert.ToInt32("98")
Convert.ToInt32("98", 16)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've always been a fan of `Integer.TryParse`  The docs for .NET 4 are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).  This method accepts an Integer variable by reference, and returns a Boolean indicating whether the conversion was successful, so you don't have to do any error handling when calling `TryParse`.

If you use the overload that accepts NumberStyle, you can specify that the string contains a hexadecimal number.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx) is the overload.

Answer (score 1):

You would convert the value to Integer with the `Parse` method:

```
Dim intValue As Integer = Integer.Parse("98")
```

To convert an hexadecimal value you can use the `AllowHexSpecifier` option:

```
Dim intValueFromHex As Integer = Integer.Parse("98", Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

You can also use the `TryParse` method if the input value can be in the wrong format:

```
Dim intValue as integer
If Integer.TryParse("98", intValue)
    Console.WriteLine(intValue)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer value")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert string "98" to the integer 98, use CInt function. For example:

```
Dim MyString As String = "98"
Dim MyInteger As Integer

MyInteger = CInt(MyString)
```

Now MyInteger = 98

Answer (score 0):

**To convert using decimal notation (base-10):**

```
Dim value = Convert.ToInt32("98")
```

or

```
Dim value = Integer.Parse("98")
```

or

```
Dim value As Integer
If Integer.TryParse("98", value) Then
  Console.WriteLine(value)
End If
```

**To convert using hexadecimal notation (base-16):**

```
Dim value = Convert.ToInt32("98", 16)
```

or

```
Dim value = Integer.Parse("98", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

or

```
Dim value As Integer
If Integer.TryParse("98", NumberStyles.HexNumber, Nothing, value) Then
  Console.WriteLine(value)
End If
```

The `NumberStyles` enumeration is in the `System.Globalization` namespace.